# Wordpress woocommerce payment gateway plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to integrate a payment gateway as a woocommerce payment gateway plugin. I placed everything as required from woocommerce payment gateway but there is one problem in redirecting. I dont know where i am wrong.

Please have a look on my php code. http://www.lovemagic.co/icicipayment.php.zip

after this code i am getting such error

[image]

i think the problem is in `function process_payment`

Please suggest me the solution.

Thank you! (In advance)

Comment: just a hutch but they could be generating that in order for you to upgrade, are you using a free or trial type version?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting what you mean to say?

Answer (score 0):

That is a WordPress Request error.

If your plugin has a sort of an API that you needed to `POST/GET` to/from and WordPress encounter an error it throw this error.

Share you code with us.